# Dynamic WPF approach to REST

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I've been working with a product which has an underlying Oracle database, usually we just reference the access provider DLL and then we can pretty must allow the user to configure things like select statement or parameterised SQL for execution on the product (they can only access their own resource via package procedures)

Recently the product has developed a new architecture whereby each possible request has a REST oData endpoint available, I'd like to still build into my applications the same level of configuration but I'm struggling to find a way forward -

Previously we could execute an anonymous block which the user could configure to suite their needs. Now it's likely that they might need to call 20 endpoints to achieve the same goal - how can I scale this?

Suggestions?

Comment: I think you are going to need some more detail in this question before it can be answered. Anonymous book of what?

Any reason you can't just bypass the application and connect to the Oracle database? That sounds like what you were doing previously

Comment: Anonymous block of PL/SQL to be executed on Oracle. To be fair it doesn't matter what it was, it's the approach for allowing a user to specify their own rest endpoints whilst still being able to programmatically access the results I'm trying to work on